# Rotate then resize based on parent's dimension

Tags: css

With CSS only (no js), is it possible to rotate a div with background image, then set the width and height to fit the screen? Can it be done without CSS SVG clipping? There's no particular reason why I don't want SVG. Just asking whether its possible or not.

I don't mind about the HTML structure. You can suggest as many div or container

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this like this 
HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="grad1"></div>
<div class="grad2"></div>
<div class="grad3"></div>
<div class="grad4"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
   body{
  background:#000;
  }
  .container{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-image: url('https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-145812.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
.grad1{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */}
    .grad2{
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right top, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */}
    .grad3{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top right, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top right, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */}
  .grad4{
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, black 50%, transparent 50.1%, transparent); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */}
```

It's a little bloated but the css could probably be halved with some use of transform. 100% responsive.
It won't work in browsers that don't support gradients. old browsers.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Buts/pen/OXxBrv)

Comment: Here's my result after using ur code http://i.imgur.com/UK988cl.png. Its a skew rect not diamond fit to screen size

Comment: Hey I have got a bit closer by setting the height and width to the same. but I don't think it will be fullscreen in both dimensions. Your questions is trickier than it seemed at first glance.

Comment: I do't have time to do it now but if you want to make it responsive both vertically and horizontally use vh and vw in the gradient settings.

Comment: i tried. but to use both vh and vw simultaneously is very tricky. I did use Pythagorean Theorem combine with vw but still failed. I don't mind waiting for the real answer. Take ur time.

Comment: @Coisox I have update the JSfiddle. it should work now I believe it is 100% responsive.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I only saw ur msg after clicking the 'Add Comment' button. I'm not so fluent in stackoverflow yet. After running ur code on Chrome and Firefox, its not working. I only saw normal rectangle.

Comment: Oh! The one that I said not working is your JSfiddle. But then I realize your edited answer seems much longer. I ran it and it is almost perfect! Thank you this is good result.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the diamond with css like the following

**html**

```
<div id="diamond"></div>
```

**css**

```
#diamond {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
#diamond:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: red;
}
```

I found and example that I think that is similar to the question that you have.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/KDbBe/)

Comment: We can't set background if using border approach. Secondly, I need the diamond to fit the screen not fixed using pixel like 50px. So I assume something like vh or %

Comment: yes that's only and example, did you check the codepen? in that example it is using some images inside the diamond

Comment: yes I've check the codepen but none meet my requirement. I need the diamond to dynamically fit viewport size or parent size. I mean if open using 1080x768 or 1900x1600, the diamond will fit

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px;float:left; }
.flip3D > .front{
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    background:url(right1.png); width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D > .back{
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
    background: url(right1.png); width:100%; height:100%; border-radius: 7px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D:hover > .front{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
.flip3D:hover > .back{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the html structure? I don't get this code

Comment: why there's a hover? and ur code demonstrate flipping effect. i need help on making a diamond (rotated 45deg rect) fill the viewport dimension